# Connecting and Apple cinema monitor to a laptop via VGA or HDMI - Possible?

Tags: hdmi, vga, dvi

I asked this over as askdifferent, but I thought I'd try here as well.

At my work, a nice big 30" Apple Cinema monitor has just become available. I would really like to use it, but I only have a laptop running Windows 7/Ubuntu 12.04.

The Apple monitor has what appears to me as a male DVI-D, and I assume it's dual link. I tried connecting it the HDMI port on my laptop using a male HDMI to female DVI-D adapter (http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=12576408). The apple monitor is recognized under both Windows and Linux, but the maximum resolution is 1200x800.

After reading this: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3571, I'm slighty confused whether this a hardware problem due to HDMI or simply a problem with me not tweaking the correct drivers.

My laptop only has vga or hdmi ouput - is it possible to buy an (active?) adapter/converter that would make hooking the screen up possible? Any price level is fine.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I'm on a nvidia geforce gtx 660M 2GB graphics card with nvidia optimus to a smaller Intel HD4600.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're out of luck. The monitor's connector is a *Dual-link DVI* connector, and HDMI (as provided by an adapter)/VGA only carries enough bandwidth for a *Single-link DVI* connector. Because of this, the total output resolution is limited to 1280x800. <sup>[Source](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3571)</sup>

(I've actually tried running 2560x1440 over an HDMI connector, and the results are very bad. Flickering horizontal lines and the monitor would lose the connection entirely if I put too many white pixels on the screen (i.e., by dragging a window onto it))

Some of the newer HDMI versions support increased bandwidth (1.3, 1.4, 2.0), but this is unavailable when using a converter to DVI.

---

If uh... you're not using that nice 30" Apple Cinema display... you could always send it to me. :)

Comment: After some additional research I came to same conclusion, but it's very nice to have it confirmed from somebody smarter!

I saw some brief mentions of active adapters, that were able to split and amplify the signal from an hdmi-output. Do these mythical creatures really exist? Again, price would be of little matter...

Comment: As far as I can tell, nobody makes an active HDMI 1.4 -> Dual-Link DVI converter. Your best bet is to get a [ViDock](http://www.villageinstruments.com/tiki-index.php?page=ViDock) and separate graphics card, or an active HDMI -> Mini DisplayPort *and* an active Mini DisplayPort -> Dual-link DVI converter. The first will be about $400-$600, and the second would be even more expensive and I don't even know if it would work.